# How to set onitemclicklistener to open strings.xml link from arraylist

Tags: java, android

I have links in strings.xml , I have arraylist that contains R.string.web_something. How can I open intent taking int ,reference to strings.xml, with web link from arraylist?

```
 places.add(new  Places(R.string.dejavu,R.string.web_dejavu,R.drawable.dejavu,R.string.web_dejavu,R.string.location_dejavu));
```

Here I need to add code to open an Intent (webpage) using link from strings.xml

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Places place = places.get(position);  //after this

        }
    });
```

tried toString(); but couse place.getWebID() returns int, it doesnt work
getWeb():

```
public int getWeb() {
    return pWebID;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?? open the website using the link(stored in arrayList)  ryt ??

Comment: @SantanuSur yes,I have a link in strings.xml , I use it in array list,and I want to open the link by clicking some item in listview(using position)

Comment: Did you tried to achieve this using some code? if so post the code so we can help you why it's not working.

Comment: @SantanuSur link in strings.xml ,array list contains reference to strings.xml , I don't know how to get String link from not reference

Comment: i have updated the answer please check..

Comment: nope,w8 I'll add code

Comment: post your `places` class

Comment: have added the answer please check use `getString(place.getWebID());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the URL from your `ArrayList which contains string resource`

*Resouce arrayList is of type Integer* .So,

```
   for(int i : yourResourceList)
       String url = getString(i);
```

Just loop through the list and you will get **each string URL** in the list

**Edit**

In your case try

```
   String place = getString(places.get(position).getWebID());
```